# Writing down a metric tensor given parametric equation of the surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, schroedinger-equation, tensor-calculus

Let me begin by saying this question isn't related to GR.

I'm reading a paper (see https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0798v1) that talks about deriving a Schrodinger equation for an electron confined on a curved surface and the result is

$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\bigg[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\sum_{i,j=1}^{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}\sqrt{g}g^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial u^j} + (H^2 - K) \bigg]\Psi = E\Psi
$$

where $g_{ij}$ is the metric tensor and $H$ and $K$ are both curvature related quantities that depend on $g_{ij}$. I'm interested on the form of this schrodinger equation for a surface described by the equation

$$z(x,y)= \alpha \cos{(\beta x)}\cos{(\gamma y)}.$$

How do I calculate for $g_{ij}$ in this case?

Answer (score 3):

A choice of basis vectors spanning the surface is 
$$\mathbf{e}_1 = \hat{x} + z_x \hat{z}, \quad \mathbf{e}_2 = \hat{y} + z_y \hat{z}$$
where I've defined $z_x = \partial z / \partial x$ and $z_y = \partial z / \partial y$. By definition, the elements of the metric satisfy
$$g_{ij} = \mathbf{e}_i \cdot \mathbf{e}_j$$
where the dot product is taken under the metric of the embedding space. So
$$g_{ij} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{e}_1 \cdot \mathbf{e}_1 & \mathbf{e}_1 \cdot \mathbf{e}_2 \\ \mathbf{e}_2 \cdot \mathbf{e}_1 & \mathbf{e}_2 \cdot \mathbf{e}_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 + z_x^2 & z_x z_y \\ z_x z_y & 1 + z_y^2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
If you want the metric in a different coordinate system, you can transform this the usual way.